# Using ImagePickerController causes my app to crash

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I researched a lot on this one. On touching an button, I have to pick an image from device and display on the screen.

But it causes my app to crash when button is touched/pressed.
It crashes from this line of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myPhotopicker animated:YES];
```

I am developing an iPad app using Xcode 4.2. I am using iPad 5.0 simulator for testing. And my system runs on Mac OS X, version 10.6.8.

Following function is called when button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        if (myPhotopicker==nil) { myPhotopicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            myPhotopicker.delegate = self; }// create once!
        myPhotopicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentModalViewController:myPhotopicker animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSString *str = @"Photo Album is not available!";     

    }   

}
```

Comment: What is the crash error you are getting in the compiler? I believe you most likely are running out of memory.

Comment: I get error which says."Thread 1: Program received signal :"SIGABRT".

Comment: SIGABRT generally means that the program threw an exception. There should be more information in the debugger console. You need to edit your question to include that information. Also, you can set a breakpoint in objc_exception_throw to get the stack trace where the exception is thrown

Comment: @Lefteris, I am sorry to say. I don't know how to check information from debugger console. can you guide me on this. Or you know any link which I can refer to?

Comment: 0x9a87bc2c  <+0000>  push   %ebp
0x9a87bc2d  <+0001>  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x9a87bc2f  <+0003>  sub    $0x18,%esp
0x9a87bc32  <+0006>  movl   $0x1,0x8(%esp)
0x9a87bc3a  <+0014>  mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x9a87bc3d  <+0017>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x9a87bc41  <+0021>  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x9a87bc44  <+0024>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x9a87bc47  <+0027>  call   0x9a87bc50 <__kill>
0x9a87bc4c  <+0032>  leave  
0x9a87bc4d  <+0033>  ret    
0x9a87bc4e  <+0034>  nop    
0x9a87bc4f  <+0035>  nop

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and can reproduce the crash in the simulator.
But it is working fine on my iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2.

That said, I made my gallery in the simulator contain some photos.
(Start in-simulator Safari, open some page, save some pictures by long pressing on them and choosing save from the menu.)

Now, the simulator writes

```
2012-05-08 15:53:55.605 test[5870:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'
```

to the console.

Okay, read, done:

```
-(IBAction)getPhoto:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) 
    {
        if (myPhotopicker==nil) {
            myPhotopicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            myPhotopicker.delegate = self;
        }// create once!
        myPhotopicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            // iPad Code:
            UIPopoverController *popover =
                [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPhotopicker];
            [popover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
        } else {
            // iPhone Code:
            [self presentModalViewController:myPhotopicker animated:YES];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Photo Album is not available!");
    }     
}
```

And now it looks like that:
[image]